# Pygame's colliderect isn't noticing collisions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Before this I used the code to say 'every button press it moves' but now I have changed it to 'when you press the button it moves in one direction until further instructions', but now the colliderect doesn't work. It worked before, and I'm still new to `pygame`. I have found a few similar issues but I think I've done what the people asking the questions have done. Any help at all is accepted.

```
import pygame, sys, random
from pygame.locals import *
from time import sleep
pygame.init()

def render():
    windowSurface.fill(black)
    player = pygame.Rect(225 + xmod,450 - ymod,30,30)
    pygame.draw.rect(windowSurface,white,player)
    pygame.draw.rect(windowSurface,white,wall_1)
    pygame.draw.rect(windowSurface,white,wall_2)
    pygame.display.update()

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500),0,32)
windowSurface.fill(black)
xmod = 0
ymod = 0
direction = 'none'
player = pygame.Rect(225 + xmod,450 - ymod,30,30)
wall_1 = pygame.Rect(0,225,250,50)
wall_2 = pygame.Rect(300,250,200,50)
render()

while True:
    render()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                direction = 'left'
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                direction = 'right'
            if event.key == K_UP:
                direction = 'up'
            if event.key == K_DOWN:
                direction = 'down'
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    if player.colliderect(wall_1) or player.colliderect(wall_2):
        xmod = 0
        ymod = 0
        player = pygame.Rect(225 + xmod,450 - ymod,30,30)
        render()
        print('again')
    if direction == 'left':
        xmod -= 1
        sleep(0.004)
    if direction == 'right':
        xmod += 1
        sleep(0.004)
    if direction == 'up':
        ymod += 1
        sleep(0.004)
    if direction == 'down':
        ymod -= 1
        sleep(0.004)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never update the global `player` variable, so it stays at its original coordinates. In the `render` function you create a new rect and assign it to a local `player` variable, but it is not the same as the global `player` which you use for the collision detection.

I suggest adding variables for the velocity `speed_x, speed_y` and adding them to the `player.x` and `.y` attributes every frame to move the rect directly.

The local `player` rect in the `render` function can be removed.

```
import sys
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *


pygame.init()

def render():
    windowSurface.fill(black)
    pygame.draw.rect(windowSurface, white, wall_1)
    pygame.draw.rect(windowSurface, white, wall_2)
    pygame.draw.rect(windowSurface, white, player)
    pygame.display.update()


black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500),0,32)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()  # A clock to limit the frame rate.

player = pygame.Rect(225, 450, 30, 30)
wall_1 = pygame.Rect(0,225,250,50)
wall_2 = pygame.Rect(300,250,200,50)

speed_x = 0
speed_y = 0

while True:
    # Handle events.
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                speed_x = -5
                speed_y = 0
            elif event.key == K_RIGHT:
                speed_x = 5
                speed_y = 0
            elif event.key == K_UP:
                speed_y = -5
                speed_x = 0
            elif event.key == K_DOWN:
                speed_y = 5
                speed_x = 0

    # Add the speed to the x and y attributes to move the rect.
    player.x += speed_x
    player.y += speed_y

    # Game logic.
    if player.colliderect(wall_1) or player.colliderect(wall_2):
        player = pygame.Rect(225, 450, 30, 30)
        print('again')

    # Render everything.
    render()

    clock.tick(60)  # Limit the frame rate to 60 FPS.
```

Comment: First, sorry, but I'm new to pygame and I'm not sure how to update the global player variable, and also, I don't want your keyup function because it's supposed to be hard to get through the gap in the wall

Comment: I was under the impression that you wanted to avoid the automatic movement. I've edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks! This helps a lot.